# Vue: npm run serve crashes when a broken link is added

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3, spacemacs

I have just started using Vue 3.

The `npm run serve` command works normally. However, once a broken link is added to the folder that npm is tracking, the `npm run serve` command crashes completely. It used to show any errors in the compiled Vue code and still keep running.

After removing the link, the `npm run serve` command can be run again to compile a working Vue project.

The crash log is as follows:

```sh
 node:internal/process/promises:225
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/brandsma/main/work/projects/vue/portfolio_main/portfolio/src/components/.#navigation.vue'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/home/brandsma/main/work/projects/vue/portfolio_main/portfolio/src/components/.#navigation.vue'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/brandsma/.npm/_logs/2020-12-25T13_56_54_511Z-debug.log
```

It seems to be a problem with the `stat` command crashing after automatically trying to follow the broken link: `.#navigation.vue`.

`.#{filename}.vue` is a link/file created by [spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/) whenever a file is edited.

npm version:

```sh
6.14.10
```

Vue version:

```sh
@vue/cli 4.5.9
```

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [configure Webpack's dev server](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver) to [ignore](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionsignored) these files:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: ['**/.#*.vue', 'node_modules/**']
    }
  }
}
```